# Unable to access internet with Ubuntu 12.04: I'm typing this on the net with wifi using the same computer on windows

Tags: networking

Downloaded Ubuntu 12.04 and believe everything is OK.  Tried many things yet am unable to connect to the internet by WiFi OR wired connections.  The computer (Dell Latitude D600) is fine because I'm using it to post this question using the WiFi and Firefox with windows. I am also unable to connect to the web using ethernet. Definitely Ubuntu and NOT the computer or web interface!  Not able to view any wireless networks. Some questions make no sense.  My FIOS router provides a WEP Key, WPS Pin and a WAN MAC: number.  Ubuntu asks for more than that and I become lost because those are the only #s I have for input!  Seeing that the computer and net interface is 100% solid and the Ubuntu download also appears to be 100%, There MUST be a simple code that will activate either WiFi, Ethernet or both!
Thank you!

I entered sudo lshw -C network and got the numbers for the router.  Don't have the slightest idea what info is required or where to enter it.
Thanks!

description: Network controller
product: BCM4306 802.11a/b/g
vendor:  Broadcom Corporation
physical id: 3
bus info: pci@0000:02:03.0
version: 03
width: 32 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: bus_master
configuration: driver=b43-pci-bridge latency=32
resources: irq:5 memory:faffe000-faffffff
Thanks!

Comment: Please edit your question to add the results of this command from the terminal: sudo lshw -C network

Comment: All the information is helpful. Please edit your question to add it all. If it is easier for you, pipe it into a text file: sudo lshw -C network > iyiyi.txt  Find the text file in your user directory and transfer it on a USB key and paste it here and give us the link in your reply: http://paste.ubuntu.com/